# PubSubHubbub error to confirm subscription

Tags: php, websub

I use this code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["hub_challenge"])) {
echo $_GET["hub_challenge"];
}
else {

}
$ch = curl_init("http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"hub.mode=subscribe&hub.verify=sync&hub.callback=http://rssreaderbg.net/pubsubbub/example/index.php&hub.topic=http://rssreaderbg.net/blog/?feed=comments-rss2");
curl_exec($ch);

file_put_contents("logmeme.txt",$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);


?><?php
if(isset($_GET["hub_challenge"])) {
echo $_GET["hub_challenge"];
}
else {

}
$ch = curl_init("http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"hub.mode=subscribe&hub.verify=sync&hub.callback=http://rssreaderbg.net/pubsubbub/example/index.php&hub.topic=http://rssreaderbg.net/blog/?feed=comments-rss2");
curl_exec($ch);

file_put_contents("logmeme.txt",$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);


?>
```

But the hub at pubsubhubbub.appspot.com gives me "Error trying to confirm subscription" ,why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to try performing a subcription verification yourself.
Send a GET request to your callback with the params as [explained in the spec](http://pubsubhubbub.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pubsubhubbub-core-0.3.html#verifysub). Make sure your callback returns a 2XX and only echoes the `hub.challenge` provided by the hub.

Comment: There's some latency ,that I didn't noticed.Now it works.Thanks!